# Where to include @Webresult ,@WebMethod etc

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jax-ws, rad

I have created a JaX Webservice through RAD(eclipse), and I am able to use the @WebParam annotation with my function parameter, however I also want to use @webresult etc but Don't know where should i specify them, on google I got interfaces but here i only have class and delegate class.

my class is

```
       public class GetFPDDataClass {

         public String GetFPDDataInput(String PolicyNumber)
         {

            return PolicyNumber;
         }

        }
```

and this is my delegate class

```
   @WebService (targetNamespace="fpd",   serviceName="GetFPDDataClassService", portName="GetFPDDataClassPort")
 public class GetFPDDataClassDelegate{

   fpd.GetFPDDataClass _getFPDDataClass = null;
     public String GetFPDDataInput (@WebParam(name="PolicyNumber") String PolicyNumber) {
      return _getFPDDataClass.GetFPDDataInput(PolicyNumber);
   }

    public GetFPDDataClassDelegate() {
        _getFPDDataClass = new fpd.GetFPDDataClass(); }

      }
```

Answer (score 12):

Both `@WebResult` and `@WebMethod` are set on the method level.

`@WebResult` is used to customize name of the XML element that represents the return value.

`@WebMethod` is used to mark business methods that are exposed to web service clients. By default all public methods in your class are exposed, if you don't implement web service interface.

Example:

```
 @WebMethod
 @WebResult(name="hellomessage")
 public String getHello() {
     ....
}
```

UPDATE:

If I dont have `@WebResult` I see the following xml:

```
<ns2:getHelloResponse>
    <return>hello fff</return>
</ns2:getHelloResponse>
```

with `@WebResult`:

```
<ns2:getHelloResponse>
   <hellomessage>hello fff</hellomessage>
 </ns2:getHelloResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to set @WebResult on my method , but that is not helping with the results in SOAPUI , should I make interface and try that